# Saving raster to BigTIFF in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, large-datasets, bigtiff

Using QGIS 3.4, I am trying to merge multiple DEMs downloaded from the National Map Viewer that are in ArcGRID format (Arc/Info Binary Grid). The output will be a large file so I can't use any of the formats limited to 2 or 4GB in size. I would like to save it as a BigTIFF but I don't know how to distinguish that from a TIFF in the merge raster dialogue box. I tried to save it as TIFF but it failed as file was over 4GB.

How do I save merged rasters as BigTIFF or, if this is not possible, how do I merge rasters to produce the smallest possible file size?

Comment: Maybe you could use a VRT file created with `gdalbuildvrt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the command that the tool is generating to the "GDAL/OGR console call" box. Read GeoTIFF driver documentation https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html and edit the command by adding one more option `-co BIGTIFF=YES` for forcing BigTIFF.

[image]

Comment: Thank you 30184. I usually use ArcMap, not Q, and I am not sure how I access the tools command parameters?

Comment: To be more specific, I don't see how I can edit them. When I click in the GDAL/OGR console call, it doesn't allow me to edit the command.

Comment: Press + in the Additional creation options panel and write "bigtiff" as a name and "yes" as a value. The command should update.

Comment: I added also a screenshot.