# RGB TIFF goes black when zoomed out in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, rgb, image-pyramids

Am importing a RGB TIFF into QGIS 3.4 and when I zoom in I can see the image properly, however, when I zoom out the layer turns black (most of it) and red (a small portion). After doing some search I found [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/6533), which suggests that this problem is caused by issues with pyramids and statistics with the layer. There is some support there but that is for ArcGIS. I tried building the pyramids in QGIS Raster-->Miscellaneous-->Build Overviews (Pyramids) (I have done it in the past for .asc files), but got the following error

```
ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Maximum TIFF file size exceeded. Use BIGTIFF=YES creation option.
ERROR 1: An error occurred while writing a dirty block from GDALRasterBand::RasterIO
```

Does anyone know how I could to build pyramids for a TIFF in QGIS?

If so, what "Overview levels" should I select?

Or does anyone know how to solve this issue for my RGB TIFF?

Comment: Can you use command line? If so use GDALAddO https://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html first with -clean to get rid of existing pyramids then use the same command with -ro so as not to internalize the pyramids. Depending on the size of your raster levels should be 4 8 16 32 64 but if very large add 128 256 to the levels. The problem comes from your GeoTIFF not being a *large GeoTIFF* and you're exceeding the 4GiB limit by internalizing your pyramids, specifying -ro will force GDALAddO to write the overviews to a separate file, thus not increasing your existing file size.

Comment: @Michael Stimson, I think your comment is worthy of posting as an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is because you're building pyramids *internally* (default) on a GeoTIFF file which is not a *[big TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#BigTIFF)*. The pyramids are being appended to the existing file which makes the resultant file exceed the 4 GiB limit. This is evident by the error message `Maximum TIFF file size exceeded`.

From here you have some options, the error message indicates using `BIGTIFF=YES` which you can do from QGIS with Raster::Translate, writing a new file which *can* exceed the 4 GiB limit, for example [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302083/saving-raster-to-bigtiff-in-qgis) describes the process.

Or if you're comfortable with the CMD tools you can attempt repair the existing TIFF file in a two step process:

1. Remove the existing bad pyramids with [GDALAddO](https://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) -clean option. It is important to remove the existing *internal* pyramids before creating new *external* pyramids as this would create a conflict of which pyramids to use; I would think that the internal pyramids would take precedence but that's an assumption - I haven't tried this to prove which takes precedence.
2. Create new *external* pyramids with [GDALAddO](https://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) -ro option which will force the creation of an OVR or RRD (–config USE_RRD YES) file to contain the pyramids. For most rasters levels of 4 8 16 32 64 (5 levels of pyramid) is sufficient but if your file is especially large use 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 to create 7 levels.

This may not work if the file is already too broken to fix, if this is the case your only option is to translate the file to a new raster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I managed to solve the issue in both ways, by using a bigTiff but also using the command line. Thanks!